# I need to get all expressions between parenteses in a mathematical operation

Tags: regex, scala

I need to get all expression between parenthesis in a mathematical operation, with scala.

I tried to do it with a regex. And it works with expressions like:

`(2+4)`-> Result: `2+4`

`4*(3+1)`-> Result: `3+1`

But It's impossible  for me to get all values, as in the following example:

`(2+1)*(4-3)`-> Result: `2+1)*(4+3`

Expected result:

```
`2+1`

`4+3`
```

Where "formula" is the input expression

```
    val regex = Pattern.compile("\\((.*)\\)")
    val regexMatcher = regex.matcher(formula)

    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        println(regexMatcher.group(1)); //Fetching Group from String
    }
```

EDIT:  In case of `(1+(2+3))`, the good result would be `1+(2+3)`

Comment: What regex did you try?

Comment: @mrzasa sorry, I had  forgotten it. I've just edit  the question, adding the regex. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use the [reluctant quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers) `*?` instead of `*` to capture only the characters until the first `)`.
2. In Scala, you don't need to double backslashes if you use triple-quoted strings, which makes regexes much more readable:

Combining:

```
Pattern.compile("""\((.*?)\)""")
```

3. As mrzasa's answer mentions, regular expressions are a wrong tool if you ever need to handle nested parentheses (but see for a caveat [How to match string within parentheses (nested) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759004/how-to-match-string-within-parentheses-nested-in-java) and [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)).

   In Scala, you can use [parser combinators](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators) instead. Huynhjl's answer to [Parsing values contained inside nested brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075677/parsing-values-contained-inside-nested-brackets) describes something which you can use as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is too greedy, it takes too much. Try

```
([^)]*)
```

this limits repetition to chars that are not a closing bracket.

In Scala it'd be probably:

```
    val regex = Pattern.compile("\\(([\\)]*)\\)")
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3OvpoX/1)

Also note that this does not support nested brackets, e.g. `(1+(2+3))`

Comment: Thanks! In case of `(1+(2+3))`, I would need `1+(2+3) `

Comment: @Doasy And regex-based approaches will give you `1+(2+3` instead (both the one here and in my answer).

Comment: You'd need recursive regexps

Comment: Using `[^)]` won't match newlines, even if you are using the DOTALL matching mode.